# How to implement signalR to two projects connected through backend service

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-web-api2

Developing a messaging application for web and mobile with real-time notification. Project flow is ..

- Backend - DataBaseOperations and Services
- Web
- APi (for mobile app)

**I need to send messages from the server to a user that can be connected from more than one location (web and mobile app)**.

Web and API works separately and access Backend. Please share suggestions what flow should I use to implement singalR in my project

Comment: Are you in a load-balanced environment?

Comment: yes .. and I am looking for any solution that can work in backend ..

Comment: What do you mean "what should I do?" It's not clear at all what you are wanting. You just described a project, not a problem. Stack Overflow is for answering specific programming problems, not assisting you with architecting your application.

Comment: I posted a question with the detail .. some VERY INTELLIGENT people marked it as BOARD .. and it was on hold .. now I posted like this ..I don't understand from where you all get SO MUCH time ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a broad question, but I'll give enough to get you started in the right direction.  Since you're going to be in load-balanced environment, *you'll need to implement a backplane*.  This sits behind your web servers and aggregates the messaging.  Here are some links that will guide you set up SignalR:

- https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api
- https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client
- https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Also, you'll need these nuget packages (minimum):

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis or SqlServer
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
- Microsoft.Owin

Comment: thank you so much for reply .. for now I am voting up the answer .. and hope soon I will be able to mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing really special in what you want to achieve.
Your client app needs to be authenticated before sending SignalR messages. That way you can identify a user and protect your server resources.
That´s the first part I would start looking into (there are tons of info about this matter if you google it).

Then you need to send a message from the server to a user and that user can have 2 client apps connected (web and mobile or even more, like other browser tabs). That can be achieved using SignalR groups.
A SignalR group is just a group of connections (not users) with a given name.
One common scenario is creating a group for each user, and that group will hold the connections of the user. This is a logical pseudo structure of how SignalR groups work (not actual code):

```
Group name: "johnUser"
Group connections: [
    00001, // mobile app connection
    00002, // brower tab connection
    00003, // broswer tab connection 2
    0000n // etc
]
```

Those numbers are simulations of Connection ids. SignalR creates them for you.
Then you just need to send a message to the group, and all connected clients will get it.

> If you are just starting with SignalR I would **not** complicate things implenting a backpane unless you really need it and you know what you are doing. A single server can handle hundreds of concurrent connections and you can scale-out later if you want.

Regarding architecture, it´s not very clear what you mean by *Web and API works separately*. It´s better if you ask more specific questions after you actually try to code something.